# Is it natural to say something is full-white?

Tags: adjectives, compounds

This is certainly not sponsored by a washing powder brand. Would it sound natural (day-to-day basis) to say that something is "full-white", meaning white in its entirety?

> e.g. This surface is full-white (fully white).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. It is completey white, it is white all over, maybe?

Comment: I was wondering if it's natural, like saying **full-time** job.

Comment: The examples I have found all relate to skin colour or ethnicity.

Comment: I see. So it probably isn't "natural"?

Comment: It might be natural but only in a specific context. Why don't you try to find examples and contexts on the internet .

Comment: One commenter said: “Ambulance just went past us in Queeny - driver head full white suit on and head helmet. Quite scary actually.” - https://www.thetelegraphandargus.co.uk/news/18225241.coronavirus-fears-bradford-hazmat-sighting-quashed/

Comment: there is your answer.